# Material Ui Angular theme not loading after footer deletion

Tags: angular, angular-material, material-ui

I was using material ui angular admin theme and I removed the footer component and deleted the imports. Now it seems that the app won't show anything but will compile. Apparently, if I delete only the footer's html, it will work, but I don't need this component. Any thoughts on this ?

Comment: what imports did you delete ?

Comment: in components.module.ts it was importing FooterComponent from footer.component so i deleted FooterComponent from declarations and exports

Comment: are you getting any errors in the console ?

Comment: @NikolaiKiefer no